# How to capture close event in EXT-GWT (GXT) window

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have this Window:

```
Window window = new Window();
window.setMaximizable(true);
window.setMinimizable(true);
window.setClosable(true);
```

And the event listener for minimize event.

```
window.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
        public void windowMinimize(WindowEvent e) {
            //...
            }
}
```

I tried:

```
window.addListener(Events.Close, new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {
      public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent be) {
      //...
      }
});
```

To capture close event (the close button)

And other events such us

> windowHide() (WindowListener) or Events.Detach (Listener)

Either i press minimize or close button it captures both of them.

*I need one separate event for the minimize and the close button.*

Answer (score 1):

closing the window fires `Events.Hide`.

if listening to the hide event failed, maybe you are overriding `hide()` or `hide(Button)` without calling `super.hide()` / `super.hide(button)`?

as an alternative, you could try to override the function `onHide()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listening to `Hide` event?

Comment: And how do you handle minimizing? Because by default there is no implementation. Whatever the problem is, it lies beyond supplied code, because by default `minimize()` method looks like this:
`public void minimize() {
   fireEvent(Events.Minimize, new WindowEvent(this));
}`. So you are handling minimize event somehow... how?

Comment: window.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
        public void windowMinimize(WindowEvent e) {